# SyntaxError: missing : after property id when html file inspection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been created slick slider.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="slick-slider">          
          <img id="graphic1" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img1_4e3a619a-0daa-439c-968b-6970fe8a7b1f_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434978806" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic2" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img1_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434488016" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic3" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img2_780e862e-5c3e-4245-82a4-e13f4bc8b19b_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434450473" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic4" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img3_ac753481-98f3-4f28-bfc5-ec9443a9ff4c_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434488053" width="564px"></a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slick-slider').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i inspect this file it shows something like this:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

May i know, how to fix this issue?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what you mention setting-name: setting-value for this line

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there is no `setting-name` option in slick.js if I am not wrong.

Secondly the JSON object provided as options to slick to js is invalid because `setting-name` has a `-` which is a substraction expression. You have to use quotes like this instead

```
$('.slick-slider').slick({
  "setting-name": "setting-value"
});
```

Based on the comments, the error `$ is not defined` is because the script files are not placed in the correct order. Your HTML file should look something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8" />
  <title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="slick-slider">          
          <img id="graphic1" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img1_4e3a619a-0daa-439c-968b-6970fe8a7b1f_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434978806" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic2" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img1_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434488016" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic3" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img2_780e862e-5c3e-4245-82a4-e13f4bc8b19b_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434450473" width="564px"></a>
          <img id="graphic4" class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/7782/products/img3_ac753481-98f3-4f28-bfc5-ec9443a9ff4c_1024x1024.jpg?v=1434488053" width="564px"></a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slick-slider').slick({
        setting-name: setting-value
      });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/kiyeno/edit?html,output**

Comment: Exactly right, with *one* nitpick: It's not a JSON object. When you're dealing with JavaScript source code, unless something is inside a string, it's not JSON, it's JavaScript. In this case, a JavaScript object initializer.

Comment: @saina: That tells you that the original problem, which prevented your code from even being parsed, has been solved by Dhiraj's answer. Now you have a *different* problem when the parsed code *runs*, which is that you need to include jQuery above your script that uses it, not below, because it's the jQuery script that defines the `$` function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for letting me know. Awesome explanation and I learnt a new thing today :)

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: 
 
i need to set carousel slider with responsive design.. actually here is my jsfiddle.net/ssqjtajj .. in this link, it works responsive design with refresh the page everytime.. still i didn't get the solution for this one.. so i move to try with slick slider... here too i m stucking..

Comment: @saina: The fiddle you have provided has a lot to work with. The solution I suggested above seems to be working fine here http://jsbin.com/kiyeno/edit?html,output

Comment: @saina: Your original question has been answered. Stack Overflow isn't for extended debugging sessions. If the answer to one question reveals a *new* question, post a *new question*. So far, Dhiraj has answered two questions for you. You should accept the answer, work with things further, and when/if you have a *new* question, post it as one.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: My jsfiddle provided is totally different from yours.. thanks.. i need same click functionality with responsive design..my current issue is , when i resize the window, image size is totally weird. but again i refresh the page.. it will display responsive..thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `-` in variables and values. You can use camel case or quotes:

```
$('.slick-slider').slick({
   settingName: settingValue,
   "setting-name": settingValue
});
```

Comment: @depperm Which is pseudo-code and invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: where? I see all settings with camelCase

Comment: @depperm don't lie and document yourself please. It's impossible to use `-` because it was made for other purposes. In values `setting-value` means an math operation that rests `setting` less `value`

Comment: may i know ..how to use kenwheeler.github.io/slick?.. because that kenwheeler styles and js files didn't apply in my html code..

Comment: It's a developer error, making confused documentation. You must to know what settings do you need and set in the function

Comment: i need to set carousel slider with responsive design.. actually here is my http://jsfiddle.net/ssqjtajj/ .. in this link, it works responsive design with refresh the page everytime.. still i didn't get the solution for this one.. so i move to try with slick slider... here too i m stucking..